# Calculate sum using Java Stream API grouping by field

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

You have two classes:

```
Account: number: String, balance: Long
Transaction: uuid: String, sum: Long, account: Account
```

Both classes have getters for all fields with the corresponding names (getNumber(), getSum(), getAccount() and so on).

I need to calculate sum of transaction for every account, but exactly not by Account, but grouping by Account.number

I make it like this:

```
Map<Account, Long> totalSumOfTransByEachAccount =
            transactions.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getAccount, Collectors.reducing(0, Transaction::getSum, Long::sum)));
```

But I need map with String key - Account.getNumber()

```
Map<String, Long> totalSumOfTransByEachAccount =
            transactions.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.  ??????)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with:

```
Map<String, Long> resultSet = transactions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getAccount().getNumber(),
                               Collectors.summingLong(Transaction::getSum)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much ) Maybe it is possible to do it with reduce?

Comment: @IvanSPb if the solution has solved your question then please feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

One more variant, my decision:

```
 Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getAccount().getNumber(),
                    Collectors.reducing(0L, Transaction::getSum, Long::sum))
```

Comment: The `Collectors.reducing` factory method is a generalization of pretty much majority of the collectors, however, I'd go with `Collectors.summingLong(Transaction::getSum)` as suggested in my answer instead of `Collectors.reducing(0L, Transaction::getSum, Long::sum)` for readability and maybe has better performance as opposed to the long-winded reducing. anyway +1 for coming up with your own answer ;-)